# Linq's Aggregate Function, How to make a CSV String

Tags: .net, linq, string, csv, aggregate

I'd like to make a comma seperated value string with Linq's Aggregate function. Anyone know how to do this?

Given an array of strings like this:

```
var authors = new string[] {"author 1", "author 2", "author 3"};
```

How do I get a single string like this ***author 1, author 2, author 3***?
I'm thinking something like `authors.Aggregate(author => author + ",")` might be able to do this but not sure.

Ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ Aggregate algorithm explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105505/linq-aggregate-algorithm-explained)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're only looking to comma-separate them, just use string.Join:

```
string.Join(", ", authors);
```

This will work with any IEnumerable<string> (at least in .NET 4.0), but has worked with arrays of strings since 1.0.

Comment: O Cool, I guess Aggregate is not really what I need. Looks like Join is the right thing. I'll give try this... thanks.

Comment: Good call - I forgot about that method!

Answer (score 7):

As Bennor McCarthy says, you'd be much better off using `string.Join` for this purpose. If you really do want to use `Enumerable.Aggregate` though, this should do:

```
string csvString = authors.Aggregate((csvSoFar, author) => csvSoFar + ", " + author);
```

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
string csvString = authors.First();

foreach (string author in authors.Skip(1))
{
    csvString += ", " + author;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ya looks like Join is much is a much simpler approach for this task.