# Automatic conversion with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

My VS2010 using ReSharper which prompts to converts `foreach` to LINQ. It converts from

```
foreach (var item in quotePrice.ExtraServiceBreakdown)
{
    hazmatRate = (quoteRequest.IsHazMat && item.Id == VitranHazmatCode) ?   
                                                 item.Cost : hazmatRate;
}
```

to

```
hazmatRate = quotePrice.ExtraServiceBreakdown.Aggregate(
                 hazmatRate, (current, item) => 
                     (quoteRequest.IsHazMat && item.Id == VitranHazmatCode) ? 
                         item.Cost : current);
```

I have two questions here,

1. What does `current` meant? Is that points to the variable `hazmatRate`?
2. What does `Aggregate` actually does?

Comment: The problem is that you're setting a variable in a `foreach` without breaking it, hence your always overwriting it. This is not efficient and possibly error-prone(if you don't want the last value).

Comment: On question #2, have you tried reading the documentation on Aggregate?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, can u explain a bit more with this?  **without breaking it,**

Comment: @DON: You can `break` a loop when you've found what you were looking for. So assuming that you actually want to find the first item with with  `id=VitranHazmatCode`, you should exit the `foreach` via `break;`. If you want to sum a number instead, you'll need to use `hazmatRate += ...` instead.

Comment: In that case also use a different Hazmat rate in the foreach loop then the one you will be increasing.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes i can understand that now and i will do that thanks

Comment: @JeroenMoonen, sorry i cant understand? can u explain it pls?

Comment: @JeroenMoonen, yeah i can now understood and here in my case i wont need that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Current indeed point to your Hazmat
2. [LINQ Aggregate algorithm explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105505/linq-aggregate-algorithm-explained)

And i think you will need to do as stated in the comment by Tim:

```
    hazmatRate += (quoteRequest.IsHazMat && item.Id == VitranHazmatCode) ?   item.Cost : hazmatRate;
```

But in this case i'd change 'hazmatRate' by a base rate declared before your function. Otherwise you would be increasing your value with the value it contained before making it grow exponentially