# Sum property values from different objects

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Data {
  public Decimal DataValueA { get; set; }
  public Decimal DataValueB { get; set; }
  public Decimal DataValueC { get; set; }
  public Decimal DataValueD { get; set; }
} // Data
```

And I have a `List<Data>`. I need to create a new `Data` object:

```
Data total = new Data();
```

Where the `DataValueA` is the sum of all `DataValueA`s in `Data` items of `List<Data>`.

The same for `DataValueB`, `DataValueC`, etc.

I was trying to do this with Linq but now sure how.

Comment: Show us what you got so far.

Comment: `total.DataValueA = yourList.Sum(r=> r.DataValueA);` ?? Is that what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Sum` but that will cause a number of iterations over the list:

```
var total = new Data
{
    DataValueA = list.Sum(x => x.DataValueA),
    DataValueB = list.Sum(x => x.DataValueB),
    DataValueC = list.Sum(x => x.DataValueC),
    DataValueD = list.Sum(x => x.DataValueD),
};
```

Or you could us `Aggregate` which will only iterate the list once:

```
var data = new[]{
            new Data{DataValueA=1,DataValueB=2,DataValueC=3,DataValueD=4},
            new Data{DataValueA=1,DataValueB=2,DataValueC=3,DataValueD=4},
            new Data{DataValueA=1,DataValueB=2,DataValueC=3,DataValueD=4},
            new Data{DataValueA=1,DataValueB=2,DataValueC=3,DataValueD=4},
        };

var result = data.Aggregate(new Data(),(a,b) => {
    a.DataValueA += b.DataValueA; 
    a.DataValueB += b.DataValueB;
    a.DataValueC += b.DataValueC;
    a.DataValueD += b.DataValueD;
    return a;
});
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/ODL27846

More info: [LINQ Aggregate algorithm explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105505/linq-aggregate-algorithm-explained/7105616)

Answer (score 2):

```
var total = new Data
{
    DataValueA = list.Sum(x => x.DataValueA),
    DataValueB = list.Sum(x => x.DataValueB),
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If multiple enumerations of the collection are OK with you, you could use `list.Sum(item => item.Property)` several times. If it is critical that you go through the list only once, for example, because it is generated through deferred execution of filters, you could use [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549218%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead:

```
var totals = list.Aggregate(new Data(), (prev, item) => {
     prev.DataValueA += item.DataValueA;
     prev.DataValueB += item.DataValueB;
     ...
     return prev;
});
```