# .net mvc 5 get X element from tuple collection in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Greetings Everyone 
I have model view that contains my method collections that I init in the main Controller but when i try to get an X element without using a `foreach` it doesn't work, I tried this in the view

```
@Html.Display(Model.Intel.where(x => x.Item2.Equals("Test"))
```

but nothing shows. If anyone have an idea i am open to it.

 `Intel` is type of `Collection<Tuple<string, string>>`

Comment: the `where` is returning an `IQueryable`.  I believe the Display is looking for a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont really need to use Display.. unless you want to create a Display Template to show the values.. just add the value to your view

```
@Model.Intel.Where(a => a.Item2 == "Test")
      .Select(a => string.Format("({0}, {1})",a.Item1, a.Item2))
      .Aggregate((i, j) => i + ", " + j)
```

assuming you might have two items with Item2 = "Test", this would output something like

```
(1 - Test), (2 - Test)
```

you can also change the string.Format to wrap the output in html tags.. just make sure you use @Html.Raw() to display it.

```
<ul>
    @Html.Raw(Model.Intel.Where(a => a.Item2 == "Test")
                   .Select(a => string.Format("<li>{0} - {1}</li>",a.Item1, a.Item2))
                   .Aggregate((i, j) => i + "" + j))
</ul>
```

would output

- 1 - Test
- 2 - Test

Comment: @JameD77 it worked but i don't understand what aggregate does & if the i, j part is needed because it's the only way ti worked for me with few tests i made, WHY? because i sometimes need to show 1 item not both of the tuple items

Comment: here's a good explanation of aggregate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105505/linq-aggregate-algorithm-explained.   `i` and `j` represent the aggregate value and the next value in the list.  the list itself is formed in the `Select`.  This is where you determine if you want Item1 and Item2 in the list or just one or the other

Comment: If you just want to display Item1 of the tuple you would replace the Select with `.Select(a => a.Item1)`  this would give you a `List<string>` since the tuple is `<string,string>`

Answer (score 0):

If Model.Intel is a collection, and you want a single string item to pass to @Html.Display, you'll need something to return a string.

```
Model.Intel.Where([predicate])
```

returns IQueryable

Try something like this to get the item, then address a property or go ToString() on it:

```
Model.Intel.Where(x => x.Item2.Equals("Test")).Single()
```

OR

```
Model.Intel.Where(x => x.Item2.Equals("Test")).Single().StringPropertyOfSingleObject
```

Comment: If he needs all of the results in one string, `Aggregate` will work.