# foreach statement cannot operate?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var maxHeight = draw._shapes.Aggregate((agg, next) =>next.height > agg.height ? next : agg);
if (draw._shapes.Count == 0)
    trackBar_Size.Maximum = 484;
else
{
    foreach (float heights in maxHeight)
    {
        if (heights < 412)
        {
            trackBar_Size.Maximum = 484;
        }
        else if (heights > 412)
        {
            trackBar_Size.Maximum = 415;
        }
    }
}
```

> Error  3   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'sCreator.Shape' because 'sCreator.Shape' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I got this error on the **var maxHeight** statement. So how do I fix this error and use the LINQ result as a float value?

Comment: `Aggregate` doesn't return collection, it returns scalar value. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105505/linq-aggregate-algorithm-explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var maxHeight = draw._shapes.Aggregate((agg, next) => next.height > agg.height ? next : agg);
            if (maxHeight.height > 412)
            {
                trackBar_Size.Maximum = 412;
            }
            else if (maxHeight.height < 412)
            {
                trackBar_Size.Maximum = 484;
            }
```

This code will get your desired Height as a float value.

Answer (score 5):

That's because `Aggregate` method returned single value (from what I can see, the greatest value in `_shapes`).

Simply, try writing `maxHeight.GetEnumerator()` to see, that compiler would complain. In order to use `foreach` loop you need to have collection (which have iterator).

Or, try writing `maxHeight.GetType()` (or `maxHeight.ToString()`) to inspect, what it really is.

Or just inspect the variable in debug mode, setting breakpoints in appropriate places.